# Frontend Rule CNAME redirect

Tags: traefik

If I want allow our user to use custom domain
example: `page.userA.com CNAME ourdomain.com`

I already made the application able to detect which page its load, but I can't get it work. It always resulting to "404 page not found", the default traefik 404 error.

At first this is our front-end rule `traefik.frontend.rule=Host:ourdomain.com`

I assume, it was because our front-end rule that was wrong, then I try to modified it to
`traefik.frontend.rule=Host:*`, then `traefik.frontend.rule=Host:ourdomain.com,*`,
but still doesn't work. Anyone have idea?

NB: our backends is docker

Answer (score 1):

There is a special 'catchall' statement you can use (paired with a priority setting):

```
traefik.frontend.rule=HostRegexp:ourdomain.com,{catchall:.*}
traefik.frontend.priority=1
```

This will capture any host not defined by other frontends.

[Source](https://www.techjunktrunk.com/docker/2017/11/03/traefik-default-server-catch-all/)